# MSMQ receive and delete

Tags: c#, .net, xml, msmq

Is there is any option to remove a message from MSMQ after it has been read?

Like, a receive + delete can run as atomic operation?

Comment: When you receive a message it's removed from the queue. What do you mean by 'delete'?

Comment: Thats what I meant, thanks, I didnt know its removed automatically after read.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you want to peek at the next message and then receive it after you're finished processing.

```
Message message = Queue.Peek();
Queue.ReceiveById(message.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the difference between Receive and [Peek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms704311%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in MSMQ?

IMO the simplest mechanism to ensure atomic operations is to place the queue operations within a TransactionScope. This can be done with WCF [like so.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789032.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789032.aspx